# Fatal error: Uncaught Error OOP php extends class

Tags: php

I did mvc app.

There is a class database in file db.php.

```
<?php
namespace App\DB_con;

class DataBase{

    static $user = "root";
    static $pass = '1234';
    static $host = "localhost";
    static $db   = "mvcApp";

     static function conn_To_DB()
    {

        $user = self::$user;
        $pass = self::$pass;
        $host = self::$host;
        $db   = self::$db;

        $conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$host", $user, $pass);
        return $conn;

    }
}
```

I inherit it in another file model_tasks.php.

```
<?php

namespace app\contol\model;
require_once 'conf/db.php';


use App\DB_con\DataBase as main_model;



class model_tasks extends main_model
{
        public function add_tasks($name, $email){
            $db  = DataBase::conn_To_DB();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO  tasks (name, mail) VALUES ('$name','$email')";
            $result = $db->prepare($sql);
            return $result->execute();

        }
}
```

Data that get into the method var_dump well.
Why the inherited class does not find the class from which it receives the connection to the database error appears! 
What am I doing wrong?

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'app\contol\model\DataBase' not found in /models/model_tasks.php:14 
Stack trace: #0 /controllers/HomeController.php(28): app\contol\model\model_tasks::add_tasks('', '', '') 
#1 /conf/route.php(28): App\Controller\BasicController::add_post() 
#2 /index.php(3): require_once('/....') 
#3 {main} thrown in /models/model_tasks.php on line 14
```

Comment: You have no `DataBase` defined in your file. You have only alias.

Comment: You will not be able to create a PDO object. You need to write `new \PDO()`

Comment: I edit DataBase on self/static and watch new error Uncaught Error: Class 'App\DB_con\PDO' not found in /conf/db.php:19

Comment: Please stop making database connection singletons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use namespace `App\DB_con\DataBase` via alias `main_model`, that's why your script doesn't know about original namespace `App\DB_con\DataBase`, it knows about alias `main_model`.

But going further as your `model_tasks` **extends** your `main_model`, all parent class methods are available in a child class.

So,

```
$db = DataBase::conn_To_DB();
```

can be changed to:

```
$db = static::conn_To_DB();  // or less secure $db = self::conn_To_DB();
```

Comment: did not help, another error appeared         Uncaught Error: Class 'App\DB_con\PDO' not found in /conf/db.php:19

Comment: Use `\PDO` as PDO is a core class - `new \PDO`, it is already mentioned in comments. And in your free time - read more about php namspaces.